# Confusion with htaccess rewrite rule for pdf directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm no htaccess expert. I've rarely used it for more than blocking dodgy spiders and the basic CI routing to remove index.php.

But basically, I'm trying to turn all requests for urls structured like:

> https://www.domain.tld/invoice/[1 or more integers]/[alphanumeric
>   string].pdf

(such as https://www.domain.tld/invoice/674/9b3vpm3cy5nd8irm.pdf)
to

> https://www.domain.tld/invoice/fetch/[1 or more integers]/[alphanumeric
>   string].pdf

(such as https://www.domain.tld/invoice/fetch/674/9b3vpm3cy5nd8irm.pdf)

So far I've got -

```
RewriteRule ^invoice/(.+)/(.+\.pdf)$ index.php?/invoice/fetch/$1 [L]
```

but it's not working correctly (unsurprisingly) and mangling requests for https://www.domain.tld/css/pdf.min.css

Can someone please help construct this rewrite rule properly? I realize this can be done easily using CI routing but I need it done in htaccess so this rule is crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem - another conflicting rewrite rule below was causing issues. I've looked further into regular expressions and have come up with a condition like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} invoice/[0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+.pdf$   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/invoice/fetch/$1 [L]
```

which seems to work great! I welcome suggestions/improvements/comments to this however.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution when rewriting slash / items. Nevertheless, you have an easy workaround:

use all your resource files with absolute path:

```
<link href="/css/pdf.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

instead of, for example,

```
<link href="../css/pdf.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This requires a rer-programming of your PHP script, or ASP.NET.

You can always test:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^invoice/([^/]+)/(.+\.pdf)$ /index.php?/invoice/fetch/$1/$2 [L]
```

the greedy regex (.+) may cause some problem.

Comment: But they are already using absolute paths. I always do for compatibility. And still, they get caught out by the rewrite. I just want the rewrite rule to *not* be targeting anything other than the structure I have proposed.

Comment: Do you use WordPress?

Comment: Nope, CodeIgniter (on this project anyway). Why do you ask?

Comment: As index.php?/invoice/fetch/$1 is not a usual URL structure.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I confused you. CodeIgniter uses Index.php as.. I can't remember the technical term but the "entry point" for all requests and 99% of people use mod rewrite in htaccess to rewrite all urls *through* that so that they're not required (and unsightly/confusing) directly in the URI.

Comment: So CodeIgniter use two PHP runs to execute one single script. Not so good.  Ok, this is not the problem for you.

Comment: No I don't think that's it, I think it just uses index.php to route requests to their appropriate controller. It's alright though, I figured out my problem - it wasn't that rewrite condition (which I've actually fixed now, after a thorough investigation into regular expressions) it was conflicting rule further down from my initial testing, d'oh!

Comment: I'm happy for you. But just a doubt, CodeIgniter runs first /index.php, and the the controller mycontroler.php, so /usr/bin/php or /usr/bin/php-cgi runs twice?

Comment: I'm not sure, the way I understood it was that index.php loads the requested Controller Class to create the object and runs. It would seem to me just one single execution of php, no?